# java swing for client

Tags: java, swing, sockets

hi friends I am creating a cyber cafe managment software in java swing where i want to exit a java software(welcome window in swing) on client machine from server.i have this code bt its not working.when client runs the programme swing window is not visible.i am able to close it from server but what i want is that swing window should be visible when client compiles and runs the code and close when i fire close command from server is it possible

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class cl extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form cl */
    public cl() {


    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 204));

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 204));

    jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\new-1.jpg")); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Welcome to our cafe");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Contact Administrator to start your session");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup
   (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(92, 92, 92)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)))
            .addContainerGap(872, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup
(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)))
            .addContainerGap(597, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
         javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,  
       javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)      


    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {


try
    {

    String s1,s2;
    Socket s=new Socket("192.168.1.2",1024);
                  DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while(true)
    {



s1=dis.readUTF();

if (s1.equals("5"))
{
System.exit(0);
}
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you never create the Frame in the main() method.

Add this code to your main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    cl frame = new cl();
    cl.setSize(640,480);
    cl.setVisible(true);
    // rest of code follows...
```

Then the frame will appear.

You might also want to investigate whether you want the user to be able to close the frame, and the [JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)

I would also suggest you consider using [java RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) rather than your own protocol. RMI might give you a lot more power / features without your needing to be hand coding networking. RMI will also mean you won't need to be running the listening in a separate thread: RMI will handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

probably not an answers to your question, please

1) don't use generated code from NetBeans, use [Standard Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

2) look for correct [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), because hard to manage bunch of code generated by `GroupLayout`

3) redirect `Socket` to the Background task, use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), [Runnable#Thread](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/), otherwise GUI will freeze until long last ended

Comment: (grin) ..but I see you are replete with probably's.  Never mind.  ;)